# Python-iris performing very slowly in reading netcdf datasets

Tags: performance, netcdf, python-iris

I recently switched from netcdf4 to iris for reading netcdf files in Python (I'm using Python 2.7). On many sides this has improved my code, but I'm having some performance problems on some datasets. Reading some files (not all of them) used to take just a few seconds with netcdf4, and takes one or more minutes with iris.

This is a simple test I used. The first reading takes 4 seconds with netcdf4 and about 90 seconds with iris! This significantly worsens my code performances, since I usually read many files for a single run.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import iris
import netCDF4 as nc

nr = 3
ifile = 'myfile.nc'

print('IRIS read\n')
for i in range(nr):
    t1 = datetime.now()
    fh = iris.load(ifile)
    data = fh[0].data
    t2 = datetime.now()

    diff = (t2-t1).total_seconds()
    print('Data loaded in {:8.3f} s\n'.format(diff))

print('NetCDF read\n')
for i in range(nr):
    t1 = datetime.now()
    fh = nc.Dataset(ifile, mode='r')
    data = fh.variables.values()[-1][:]
    t2 = datetime.now()

    diff = (t2-t1).total_seconds()
    print('Data loaded in {:8.3f} s\n'.format(diff))
```

Has someone found the same behaviour? Is it something I'm doing wrong with iris?

Comment: To my understanding calling ".data" on the iris cube will immediately load the data into a numpy array. For netcdf you get just the netcdf "Variable" object from the variables-dict. You would need to copy the data to numpy array by appending "[:]".

Comment: you're right, I edited the example above. Anyway netcdf4 takes the same time if I add [:], so the problem is there..

Comment: Then I can only speculate, that the data you claim with iris (index 0) is different from the variable retrieved using netcdf4 (index -1).

Comment: I can assure you it is the same variable. The files in the example only have one variable, but netcdf4 reads also the coordinates as variables (the last one being the true variable). The real point is what is iris doing in that time?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that iris is really doing a lot more work than netCDF4 in this case. This is because it knows about the CF conventions and will automatically identify coordinates (both dimensional and auxiliary) and read a lot of metadata from the file to produce a nice cube that gives you not only the naked data, but puts you in a position to actually understand it.

As a result, the contents of `fh` in the iris case is not the same as in the netCDF4 case at all. When I ran your program on a test file and printed the `data` in both cases, the pure netCDF4 actually delivered some coordinate data (1d latitudes in my case), not the actual data at all.